# Testing Stored Procedures with MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, stored-procedures

What is the best way to test MySQL stored procedures? How do you test stored procedures with output parameters in the MySql GUI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My standard method is to create SQL scripts that create the test data, call the stored procedure, and automatically verify the post-conditions of the stored procedure.  You could use the MySQL Query Browser to write/run the scripts.

HTH -

Chris